# Why do I get a Build Error on Tab Bar Tap?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uitabbar, build-error

I am creating an iPhone iOS Application. I have 3 tabs in a tab bar controller. When I tap on the third tab on the tab bar controller in iOS Simulator, iOS simulator disappears and I am shown the main.m file with a green highlight over:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

The build error states that: Thread 1: Program received signal: SIGABRT

If I look at the build output window at the bottom of the screen, I see the following text:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 4283.
**2011-07-03 12:45:37.114 Cypher Bot[4283:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4e1b190> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key portraitView.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dce5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f22313 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dce4e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
        3   Foundation                          0x007a0677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
        4   Foundation                          0x007a05e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
        5   UIKit                               0x0021c30c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
        6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d448cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
        7   UIKit                               0x0021ad23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
        8   UIKit                               0x0021cab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
        9   UIKit                               0x000d2628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
        10  UIKit                               0x000d0134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
        11  UIKit                               0x000d000e -[UIViewController view] + 56
        12  UIKit                               0x000e2f54 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 120
        13  UIKit                               0x000e1aaa -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
        14  UIKit                               0x000e38a2 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263
        15  UIKit                               0x000e3711 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 352
        16  UIKit                               0x000204fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
        17  UIKit                               0x00222ce6 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 422
        18  UIKit                               0x000204fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
        19  UIKit                               0x000b0799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
        20  UIKit                               0x000b2c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
        21  UIKit                               0x000b0750 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49
        22  UIKit                               0x000204fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
        23  UIKit                               0x000b0799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
        24  UIKit                               0x000b2c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
        25  UIKit                               0x000b17d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
        26  UIKit                               0x00044ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
        27  UIKit                               0x00025c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
        28  UIKit                               0x0002af2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
        29  GraphicsServices                    0x01007992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x00daf944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
        31  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0fcf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
        32  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0cf83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
        33  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0c840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
        34  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0c761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
        35  GraphicsServices                    0x010061c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
        36  GraphicsServices                    0x01006289 GSEventRun + 115
        37  UIKit                               0x0002ec93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
        38  Cypher Bot                          0x00002889 main + 121
        39  Cypher Bot                          0x00002805 start + 53
        40  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)**
>
```

The changes I made to the third view controller just before this were:

1. Add Support for Landscape
2. Add Memory Warning Event
3. Add a feature that allows you to open the SMS app (I have deleted that, and then I ran the project but nothing happened)

EDIT:
I have included the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;
    IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
@end
```

The @properties are used with @synthesize and there are no errors or warnings in the project.

EDIT 2: I have removed everything related to portraitView and landscapeView and now when I run it and I tap More, I get the following:

```
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Spencer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/1E0A4C15-2143-442D-A8FC-4AE36CFC90E4/Cypher Bot.app> (loaded)' with name 'ThirdViewController.xib''**
```

What am I doing wrong? How come I can't tap on the third tab?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key portraitView' looks like the error -- are you using a variable called portraitView anywhere?

Comment: Yes I am using an IBOutlet UIView *portraitView; I also use it with @property and @synthesize.

Comment: I have gone over my header files, and it seems that nothing is wrong with them, the xib files have all of their outlets linked, and I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Double check that your .xib refers to 'ThirdViewController' ?

Comment: Is it possible that Xcode doesn't allow landscape mode with a tab bar? Is that why I might be getting this error?

Comment: The error suggests that the problem comes from binding your .xib to your ThirdViewController... it's trying to set 'portraitView' and it doesn't exist on the view controller you are referencing from the .xib. Did you double check that the xib is totally correct? I don't think it has to do with the landscape mode..

Comment: I have reviewed almost everything, and it all links to the correct .xib file. The third view controller was added to the project later and was not included in the template. Because it was added later, does that mean it is a different format or that I can not use it with UITabbar controller?

Comment: Is that ThirdViewController.xib part of your build target? (Check the copy resources section)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your nib file tries to bind something to an outlet named `portraitView` on a UIViewController, but UIViewController does not have such a property. I'd guess you need to go into IB and change the class on that view controller to whichever custom UIViewController subclass in your application it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

[image: IB Snapshot]

Here is my view in Interface Builder. "File's Owner" should be set to the corresponding view controller, in your case, it should say "ThirdViewController" here. Make sure you are linking to the correct view controller.

Also check the code where you add this view controller to the tab bar. Are you init-ing a UIViewController or a ThirdViewController? Make sure it's a ThirdViewController.

Comment: It sounded like a great solution, but it sin't working for me. Where would I find the place where Xcode is init-ing a UIViewController?

Comment: When you create your tab bar controller, you give it view controllers that serve as your 'tabs' - this probably happens when your app starts up. It's in your code somewhere. Here you must make sure you are creating a `ThirdViewController and not just a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Bradley
I have tried everything you have suggested. There is something I must be doing wrong. I have used a Tab Bar Template, added a UIViewController Subclass, and then linked them all together in their own nibs and in the main window nib and the app delegate. Should I just start a new project and copy all my stuff over to the project? Is there anything else i can do?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably changed the name of the variable name in the code after you dragged the view in the interface builder to that variable, that causes such errors. To fix you have to drag it over again, you probably have a explanation mark in the interfacebuilder at that property.